# failed to open stream:

Tags: php, laravel, веб-программирование

При попытке подключения файла выдает ошибку: include(frontend/advtool.blade.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory (View: W:\domains\laravel\laravel\resources\views\home.blade.php)

```
<?php

include 'frontend/advtool.blade.php';

    ?>
```

Comment: а так: `include __DIR__ .  '/frontend/advtool.blade.php';` ?

Comment: а что вы делаете таким способом в laravel ? для рендеринга шаблона в контроллере есть свои методы https://laravel.ru/docs/v5/quickstart

Comment: не помогло include __DIR__ . '/frontend/advtool.blade.php';

Comment: мне нужно вызвать одну переменную из этого файла

Comment: а что она там делает? Почитайте о шаблоне MVC.

Comment: при чем тут вообще mvc?

Comment: а что такое Laravel? какая у него архитектура? скажите, пожалуйста

Comment: Laravel — бесплатный веб-фреймворк с открытым кодом, предназначенный для разработки с использованием архитектурной модели MVC (англ. Model View Controller — модель-представление-контроллер). Laravel выпущен под лицензией MIT.

Comment: ну и какую переменную вы храните в шаблоне? разве в MVC данные получают из шаблона?

Comment: $sp = ($fc + $gp +$cp + $rr + $vp + $cs + $io)/7;